# Virtual host or Proxy to a WebApplication with Apache 2.2 and Tomcat 6

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a server app with Apache 2.2 (+mod_jk) + Apache Tomcat 6.0 that works fine. I can get to the web application's home page typing http://the_ip/application in the browser. But I want to access that page at the root address http://the_ip. Right now I am getting Tomcat's Root page
Can someone point me to a doc or posting that explains how to proceed with this?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set webapp `application` as the default web app (i.e. access it directly via http://localhost:8080/), then you can set the path as `""` in `Context` within `<Host>` in `server.xml`
. This should work

```
<Context docBase="/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/application/" path="" reloadable="true>
```

From the Tomcat docs,

> If you specify a context path of an
>   empty string (""), you are defining
>   the default web application for this
>   Host, which will process all requests
>   not assigned to other Contexts

Note: From the Tomcat 6 docs http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Introduction it is recommended not to put this in server.xml since you need to restart Tomcat for any changes.

> The default web application may be
>   defined by using a file called
>   ROOT.xml

but i have not tried that option myself

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work this way. I guess I'll have to proxy it from Apache

Comment: Peter: does it still show the default tomcat page if you hit it without apache?

Comment: Actually I've made it work with your suggested solution. The only modification to it is that I had to add <b>override="true"</b> as per the apache documentation. 
Also as a side note, I am using Apache 2.2 as the web server and mod_jk to proxy to Tomcat 6 so that the configuration did not take effect right away. I had to first stop Tomcat, then stop Apache, start Tomcat, and start Apache to flush out the caches that mod_jk may use.
Thanks for your suggestion. 
Peter

Comment: Ah, good point on restarting Apache and Tomcat too. Glad it worked.